# How to read streamdata in xml when unknown stream type

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to build a plugin for a program that seems to save its dataSets in XML files. When I read the file back into a dataset in my plugin, I see the fields in the xml file, and one of them is "StreamData" which then has a long string of random characters: Bhl0bEVzdG....and so on. As I don't have the source code for the original program, I don't know what kind of object this is I need to try to read this data into to recreate the nice/normal looking dataTable from the program.

Here's the code to read in the xml file

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(stream, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet;
foreach (DataTable t in dataSet.Tables)
{
    dataGridView1.DataMember = t.TableName;
}
```

This makes a table that looks like the xml file, but I want a table that looks like the table that made the xml file, if that makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: `a long string of random characters: Bhl0bEVzdG.` It is probably [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded string

Answer (score 0):

Try using `System.Xml.Linq` to read and process the XML.

You can read the file into an `XDocument` and access it's elements like this:

`XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream)`

`var allDescendants = d.Descendants("StreamData").ToArray();`

Once you get all the data you want from the `XDocument` you can manually place it into a `DataTable`.

Here is more specific information about `System.Xml.Linq` and `DataTables`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Linq is very useful and I have found it solves many problems very elegantly.